# combining rows in sequence file

Tags: r

I have a data frame, in which each individual has two rows and I want to combine these two row in on row.

Code lines:

```
dat <- read.table("cbin.csv",sep="\t", row.names=1)
dat
    V2 V3 V4 V5
1_1  A  B  C  D
1_2  a  b  c  d
2_1  E  F  G  H
2_2  e  f  g  h
3_1  J  K  L  M
3_2  j  k  l  m

d <- apply( dat[ , colnames(dat) ] , 2 , paste , collapse = " " )
d
   V2            V3            V4            V5 
"A a E e J j" "B b F f K k" "C c G g L l" "D d H h M m"
```

But I want to combine each two rows like this

```
1  A a B b C c D d
2  E e F f G g H h
3  I i J j K k L l
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you more or less the data.frame you want. I just pull out the even rows and `cbind` them next to the odd rows.

```
dat2 <- cbind(dat[seq(1, nrow(dat), by = 2), ],
              dat[seq(2, nrow(dat), by = 2), ])
```

I'll leave reordering the columns (or pasting them together, if you want to combine them into individual strings) as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options:

Option 1: Use `stack` to get a long `data.frame`, then use `paste` within `aggregate` to get the output you want.

Here's how you make your "long" `data.frame`.

```
Long <- cbind(rn = rownames(dat), stack(dat)) 
head(Long)
#    rn values ind
# 1 1_1      A  V2
# 2 1_2      a  V2
# 3 2_1      E  V2
# 4 2_2      e  V2
# 5 3_1      J  V2
# 6 3_2      j  V2
```

If the values in "dat" are `factor`s, you might need to do:

```
Long <- cbind(rn = rownames(dat), stack(lapply(dat, as.character)))
```

Once your data are in a long form, use `aggregate` along with `substr` (among other choices) to get the values you need to `paste` together.

```
aggregate(values ~ substr(rn, 1, 1), Long, paste, collapse = " ")
#   substr(rn, 1, 1)          values
# 1                1 A a B b C c D d
# 2                2 E e F f G g H h
# 3                3 J j K k L l M m
```

---

An alternative is a similar approach to what @Gregor is suggesting. This is basically an alternative approach to getting every alternate row and binding it, but goes the extra step to reorder and paste the values together.

```
do.call(paste, 
        cbind(dat[c(TRUE, FALSE), ], 
              dat[c(FALSE, TRUE), ])[order(rep(names(dat), 2))])
# [1] "A a B b C c D d" "E e F f G g H h" "J j K k L l M m"
```